# Can't Sort y axis values plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart, yaxis

I would like to sort my y-axis but I can't. I am working with Plotly and I don't understand. I used a Pandas melt function to have it all in 3 columns, it works but when I do the grouped bar chart, the y axis is weird! I have tried to sort it but no result! You can see the grouped bar plot with a weird y-axis:

[image]

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot

histo_prof=pd.melt(df,id_vars=['sequence'],var_name='indiceall', value_name='valeur')
 

Output:
          sequence      indiceall  valeur
0         (0, 50]          indice  14525
1       (50, 100]          indice   1552
2      (100, 200]          indice   1475
3      (200, 500]          indice    413
4     (500, 1000]          indice    115
5    (1000, 5000]          indice    274
6   (5000, 10000]          indice     21
7         (0, 50]  indicebssverif    458
8       (50, 100]  indicebssverif    548
9      (100, 200]  indicebssverif    275
10     (200, 500]  indicebssverif    163
11    (500, 1000]  indicebssverif    139
12   (1000, 5000]  indicebssverif    269
13  (5000, 10000]  indicebssverif     53
14        (0, 50]    indicelogiso   5153
15      (50, 100]    indicelogiso   1850
16     (100, 200]    indicelogiso   1030
17     (200, 500]    indicelogiso    549
18    (500, 1000]    indicelogiso    255
19   (1000, 5000]    indicelogiso    482
20  (5000, 10000]    indicelogiso     23

#Grouped bar plot
fig_histoprof = px.bar(histo_prof, x="sequence", color="indiceall",
             y='valeur',
             title="Comparatif de la profondeur des forages/sondages ",
             barmode='group'
            )
plot(fig_histoprof)
```

Please help me, I know it will be easy for you, thank you!

Comment: Could you share a sample of the original data (before the melt)? That would help to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `melt` results in that values are `objects`, not `float` or `int`. You cant fix this by using:

```
histo_prof.value.astype(np.float64)
```

I just re-created your dataframe (called `forage`below) and imported it as a csv file:

```
forage = pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\k_sego\forage.csv", sep=";")
```

which is

```
        sequence       indiceall  valeur
0         (0, 50]          indice   14525
1       (50, 100]          indice    1552
2      (100, 200]          indice    1475
3      (200, 500]          indice     413
4     (500, 1000]          indice     115
5    (1000, 5000]          indice     274
6   (5000, 10000]          indice      21
7         (0, 50]  indicebssverif     458
8       (50, 100]  indicebssverif     548
9      (100, 200]  indicebssverif     275
10     (200, 500]  indicebssverif     163
11    (500, 1000]  indicebssverif     139
12   (1000, 5000]  indicebssverif     269
13  (5000, 10000]  indicebssverif      53
14        (0, 50]    indicelogiso    5153
15      (50, 100]    indicelogiso    1850
16     (100, 200]    indicelogiso    1030
17     (200, 500]    indicelogiso     549
18    (500, 1000]    indicelogiso     255
19   (1000, 5000]    indicelogiso     482
20  (5000, 10000]    indicelogiso      23
```

I did exactly what you did:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
fig_histoprof = px.bar(forage, x="sequence", color="indiceall",
             y='valeur',
             title="Comparatif de la profondeur des forages/sondages ",
             barmode='group'
            )
plot(fig_histoprof)
```

which returned what I think you're looking for:

[image]

Try to use groupby instead of melt. The thing is that `melt` results in that values are `objects`, not `float` or `int`.